# How to create a system image file of an OS with some software programs already installed?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10, disk-image

Is it possible to create an install-able system image of an operating system (like Ubuntu, Windows 10) such that it has a bunch of programs already installed when the OS is installed?

Whenever I choose to reinstall my OS, the biggest problem I face is the time and effort it takes to install my required software programs *after* installing the actual OS. So I am looking for a solution for that.

The required software not only includes the common programs like Google Chrome and Skype, but also others like database servers, XAMPP and IDEs.

Comment: Yes; You can use DISM to create a .wim image which can be applied to any partition.

Comment: boot to audit mode during install, install all programs, sysprep generalize the image, capture a new WIM

Comment: Why is this question has so many downvotes? I don't think this is inappropriate for the superuser forum.

Comment: The problem with the question is that it's overly general, including both Windows and Ubuntu Linux (completely different procedures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is of course why you think you need to reinstall your OS in the first place -- I've upgraded my Debian Linux installation over the last 20 years or so, but I never reinstalled it.

Making installation CDs is probably impractical, because you'll need too many CDs too install a reasonable amount of software. It's much better to just pick a configuration and automate the installation of the necessary packages.

There are tools like [FAI](http://fai-project.org/) (Fully Automatic Installation) aimed at installing indentical images on many machines that do that for a wide range of Linux distributions. But of course it will also work for a single machine.

Comment: This doesn't give you your applicatons configurations and data back. They are largely preserved separately from the software (in /home on Linux and in your profile on Windows) but there will be exceptions.